# Ajax send form values for executing credit card function validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

How can I check dinamically entered values on input fields with onChange function in jQuery / Ajax for CreditCard class? Codes are below:

----> checkout.php file <----

```
<form action="payment.php" method="post" id="s-form" class="s-form">

  <label>Card Number ?</label>
      <input type="text" name="ccCardNumber" id="ccCardNumber" required>
  </label>                  
  <span class="error-ccCardNumber"></span>

  <label>CVV|CVC|CID</label>
      <input type="text" name="ccCVV" id="ccCVV" required>
  </label>
  <span class="error-ccCVV"></span>

  <label>Month ?</label>
      <input type="text" name="ccMonth" id="ccMonth" required>
  </label>
  <label>Year ?</label>
      <input type="text" name="ccYear" id="ccYear" required>
  </label>
  <span class="error-ccMonthYear"></span>

  <button type="submit" name="checkoutNEW" class="button">CHECKOUT</button>

</form>


<script>
  $('#ccCardNumber, #ccMonth, #ccYear, #ccCVV').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'GET',
        url         : '_ccAjax.php',
        data        : { ccCardNumber: $('#ccCardNumber').val(), ccMonth: $('#ccMonth').val(), ccYear: $('#ccYear').val(), ccCVV: $('#ccCVV').val() },
        dataType    : 'php',
        beforeSend  : function() {
            $('.err-ccCardNumber').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" width="24" height="24" />');
        },
        success     : function(response) {
            $('.err-ccCardNumber').html(response);
            $('.err-ccCVV').html(response);
            $('.err-ccMY').html(response);
        },
        error       : function() {
            $('.err-ccCardNumber').text('Invalid card number!');
            $('.err-ccCVV').text('Invalid CVV2/CVC2 Number!');
            $('.err-ccMY').text('Credit card has been expired!');
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

----> _ccAjax.php file <----

```
<?php 
  require_once "_ccMod10.php";

  $CARDTYPE = $ErrArr = NULL; 
  $cc = new CCVal($_GET["ccCardNumber"], $_GET["ccMonth"], $_GET["ccYear"], $_GET["ccCVV"]);
  $cstatus = $cc -> IsValid();

  if($cstatus[0] == "Success") {
      $CARDTYPE = $cstatus[1];
      $_GET["ccCardNumber"] = $cstatus[2];
      $_GET["ccCVV"] = $cstatus[3];
  } else {
      $ErrArr = $cstatus;
  }
?>
```

----> _ccMod10.php file <----

```
<?php 
class CCVal 
{ 
var $__ccType = ''; 
var $__ccNum = ''; 
var $__ccExpM = 0; 
var $__ccExpY = 0;
var $__ccCVV = ''; 

function CCVal($num, $expm, $expy, $cvv) 
{

    if(!empty($num)) 
    { 
      $cardNumber = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $num); 
      if(!empty($cardNumber)) 
      { 
        $this->__ccNum = $cardNumber; 
      } 
    } 

    if(!empty($cvv)) 
    { 
      $cardCVV = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $cvv); 
      if(!empty($cardCVV)) 
      { 
        $this->__ccCVV = $cardCVV; 
      } 
    } 

    if(!is_numeric($expm) || $expm < 1 || $expm > 12) 
    { 
      $this->__ccExpM =NULL;
    } 
    else 
    { 
      $this->__ccExpM = $expm; 
    } 

    $currentYear = date('Y');
    settype($currentYear, 'integer');
    $expy=$expy+2000;
    if(!is_numeric($expy) || $expy < $currentYear || $expy > $currentYear + 15) 
    { 
      $this->__ccExpY = NULL; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
      $this->__ccExpY = $expy; 
    }

    if (ereg("^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$", $this->__ccNum)) {
        $this->__ccType = MASTERCARD;}
    elseif (ereg("^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$", $this->__ccNum)) {
        $this->__ccType = VISA;}
    elseif (ereg("^3[47][0-9]{13}$", $this->__ccNum)) {
        $this->__ccType = AMEX;}
    elseif (ereg("^3(0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}$", $this->__ccNum)) {
        $this->__ccType = DINNERS;}
    elseif (ereg("^6011[0-9]{12}$", $this->__ccNum)) {
        $this->__ccType = DISCOVER;}
    elseif (ereg("^(3[0-9]{4}|2131|1800)[0-9]{11}$", $this->__ccNum)) {
        $this->__ccType = JCB;}
    elseif (ereg("^(5[06-8]|6)[0-9]{10,17}$", $this->__ccNum)) {
        $this->__ccType = MAESTRO;}
    else {
        $this->__ccType = UNKNOWN;}
}

function IsValid() 
{ 

  $validFormat = false; 
  $validExp = false;
  $passCheck = false;
  $validCVV = false;
  $testCard = false;

switch($this->__ccType) 
{ 
  case MASTERCARD: 
    $validFormat = true;
    break; 
case VISA: 
    $validFormat = true;
    break; 
case AMEX: 
    $validFormat = true;
    break; 
case DISCOVER: 
    $validFormat = true;
    break; 
case DINNERS: 
    $validFormat = true;
    break; 
case JCB: 
    $validFormat = true; 
    break; 
case MAESTRO: 
    $validFormat = true; 
    break; 
  default: 

  $validFormat = false; 
}

$cardExpM = $this->__ccExpM; 
$cardExpY = $this->__ccExpY;

if($cardExpM && $cardExpY && date('Ym')<=$cardExpY.$cardExpM) {
$validExp = true;
}

$cardCVV = $this->__ccCVV; 

if($cardCVV && (strlen($cardCVV)==3 && $this->__ccType!=AMEX)) {
$validCVV = true;
} elseif($cardCVV && (strlen($cardCVV)==4 && $this->__ccType==AMEX)) {
$validCVV = true;
}

$cardNumber = strrev($this->__ccNum); 
$numSum = 0; 

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($cardNumber); $i++) 
{ 
  $currentNum = substr($cardNumber, $i, 1); 

if($i % 2 == 1) 
{ 
  $currentNum *= 2; 
} 

if($currentNum > 9) 
{ 
  $firstNum = $currentNum % 10; 
  $secondNum = ($currentNum - $firstNum) / 10; 
  $currentNum = $firstNum + $secondNum; 
} 

$numSum += $currentNum; 
}

$passCheck = ($numSum % 10 == 0);

$testCard = in_array($this->__ccNum,array('340000000000009','341111111111111','343434343434343','346827630435344','370000000000002','370000200000000','370407269909809','370556019309221','371449635398431','374200000000004','376462280921451','377752749896404','378282246310005','378734493671000','30000000000004','30569309025904','5019717010103742','30204169322643','30218047196557','30221511563252','36000000000008','36148900647913','36700102000000','38000000000006','38520000023237','6011000000000004','6011000000000012','6011000400000000','6011000990139424','6011111111111117','6011153216371980','6011601160116611','6011687482564166','6011814836905651','201400000000009','201481123699422','214925980592653','214983972181233','180001638277392','180040153546898','180058601526635','3528000700000000','3528723740022896','3530111333300000','3566002020360505','3569990000000009','630495060000000000','6304900017740292441','6333333333333333336','5100080000000000','5105105105105100','5111111111111118','5123619745395853','5138495125550554','5274576394259961','5301745529138831','5311531286000465','5364587011785834','5404000000000001','5424000000000015','5431111111111111','5454545454545454','5459886265631843','5460506048039935','5500000000000004','5500939178004613','5555555555554444','5565552064481449','5597507644910558','6334580500000000','6334900000000005','633473060000000000','6767622222222222222','6767676767676767671','5641820000000005','6331101999990016','6759649826438453','4007000000027','4012888818888','4024007127653','4222222222222','4556069275201','4556381812806','4911830000000','4916183935082','4916603452528','4929000000006','4005550000000019','4012888888881881','4111111111111111','4444333322221111','4539105011539664','4544182174537267','4716914706534228','4916541713757159','4916615639346972','4917610000000000','4406080400000000','4462000000000003','4462030000000000','4917300000000008','4917300800000000','4484070000000000','4485680502719433'));

  if($validFormat && $validExp && $validCVV && $passCheck && !$testCard) {
      return array("valid",$this->__ccType,$this->__ccNum,$this->__ccCVV);
  } else {
  $ERR=NULL;
  if(!$validFormat || !$passCheck) $ERR[]="Invalid card number";
  if(!$validCVV) $ERR[]="Invalid CVV2/CVC2 Number";
  if(!$validExp) $ERR[]="Credit card has been expired";  
  if($testCard) $ERR[]="Reserved card number";
  return $ERR;
  }
 } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: you need to return/echo something in your `_ccAjax.php` file to tell ajax what's going on;

Comment: I already did what you said, but I cannot do well

Comment: how can I show success OR error messages ??

Comment: i can't see that in your code ! however, `dataType    : 'php',` this is wrong, remove this line

Comment: before it was html after I changed to php. now I remove it still not working  :( anyway I put to _ccAjax.php these lines below:

if (!isset($_GET['ccCardNumber'])) $ErrArr[0];
if (!isset($_GET['ccCVV'])) $ErrArr[1];
if (!isset($_GET['ccMonth']) && isset($_GET['ccYear'])) $ErrArr[2];

and put the variables $ErrArr[0], $ErrArr[1], $ErrArr[2] to their self error tag of <span>

BUT STILL NOT WORK!